# Nulls being inserted into MySQL database in error

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to run some simple PHP code that pulls in a JSON formatted file and inserts into a database.

The code returns that a new record was created succesfully. However, when I look at the databse every value is 0.

```
//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('http://tally.fit/empdetails.json');

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//get the employee details
$id = $data['empid'];
$name = $data['personal']['name'];
$gender = $data['personal']['gender'];
$age = $data['personal']['age'];
$streetaddress = $data['personal']['address']['streetaddress'];
$city = $data['personal']['address']['city'];
$state = $data['personal']['address']['state'];
$postalcode = $data['personal']['address']['postalcode'];
$designation = $data['profile']['designation'];
$department = $data['profile']['department'];

//insert into mysql table
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_emp(empid, empname, gender, age, streetaddress, city, state, postalcode, designation, department)
VALUES('$id', '$name', '$gender', '$age', '$streetaddress', '$city', '$state', '$postalcode', '$designation', '$department')";
```

JSON:

```
{
    "emp": "SJ011MS",
    "personal": {
        "name": "Smith Jones",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": "28",
        "address": {
            "streetaddress": "7 24th Street",
            "city": "new york",
            "state": "NY",
            "postalcode": "10038"
        }
    },
    "profile": {
        "designation": "Deputy General",
        "department": "Finance"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `echo $id;` to see what's in the variables? Does that give a value of null, or the actual ID? This might help you with debugging.

Comment: If nothing else - your JSON has `emp` for the employee ID, and you're using `empid`

Comment: You're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I fixed the JSON then I added echo and I can see each value coming through just fine..   What is strange now is not all fields are being updated in the db, only some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is not valid. See below.

```
"profile":{
            "designation":"Deputy General",
            "department":"Finance", //Remove Comma here for valid JSON
            }
```

You can test this in the future by using `var_dump()` on your `json_decode()` and then validate your JSON string with a [JSON Validation tool](http://jsonlint.com/#).

Answer (score 0):

This JSON string returned by the server is not valid. Can't be parsed with json_decode.